# Wifi Not Working with Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and Pi 3b+

Tags: wifi, linux, pi-3b+, ubuntu, connection

I was able to get Ubuntu MATE to finally run on my Pi 3B+ after following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdJrd75_068&lc=z234tvgocvmqyzb5a04t1aokgml1ll00iwv1gbnt2da0rk0h00410.1542100861012450.

However, I'm still having issues making the wifi work. I am able to enable networking and edit connections, but I can't seem to actually connect to the wifi.

I have already tried the following steps to try to fix the wifi:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManger.conf
```

--> I changed "false" to "true."

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service NetworkManager restart
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
sudo reboot
```

Does anyone have a solution to this wifi issue?

Comment: Please clarify `having issues to make it work`. Is wlan not coming up or is it some other problem? Have you checked relevant log files for any error messages? Did you install the firmware for the 3B+ network devices (it uses a different chipset than the 3B)?

Comment: I'm not able to connect to any of the wifi. I can see all the connections via the connection manager, where I can see the last time each wifi was modified and the usernames/passwords for the wifi. However, I can't actually connect to any of the wifi. Wlan isn't coming up. There aren't any error messages I'm getting, though. What is the firmware for the 3B+ network devices?

Comment: `What is the firmware for the 3B+ network devices` that should be explained in your video (sorry, I don't do video tutorials. Cannot watch most of them for more than a minute and the ones from your YT video creator I have to quit after about 15 seconds). Maybe you need to find a more recent source for the update. I have no idea which is a correct/good one.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi 3B+ has new hardware for Ethernet, WiFi, Bluetooth and Power management.

As a consequence it requires new Firmware, different Device Tree settings and possibly kernel changes.

There is no current support for MATE on the Pi3B+. A number of people have managed to get the Pi3B+ working (or partially working) by installing the Foundation Firmware and kernel - but this is untested and the interfacing to software may have issues.

There is development on Ubuntu MATE for the Pi but it seems unlikely that there will ever be Ubuntu MATE 16.04 for the Pi3B+. Ubuntu MATE 18.04 will likely be using a standard Ubuntu kernel See https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/status-of-ubuntu-mate-18-04-for-raspberry-pi-3-b-b/18054/6

Do you REALLY need MATE? MATE is not officially supported by Canonical and the Pi support is marginal at best. Raspbian is supported, and you can install the MATE desktop on a Pi if you want.