# Ubuntu 16.04 Raspberry Pi 3B+ Install Failure

Tags: ubuntu

[ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz](http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3/ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz) was flashed for a Raspberry Pi 3 B+.  Bootup halts at the [rainbow screen](https://lifehacker.com/what-the-raspberry-pis-rainbow-boot-screen-and-rainbow-1768470271):

[image] When the SD card is flashed with Raspbian the system works correctly (hardware is not defective and power supply is good.).

Is there any reason not to expect bespoke 16.04 image not to work on pi-3B+?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wifi Not Working with Ubuntu MATE 16.04 and Pi 3b+](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/90883/wifi-not-working-with-ubuntu-mate-16-04-and-pi-3b)

Comment: @Milliways  Are you suggesting that the video at t=272 features the solution by booting up the image on an rpi3 and updating it with the command `sudo update`?  https://youtu.be/tdJrd75_068?t=272    I ask because I have only the rpi3&4 and Zero-W

Comment: I wouldn't know what is in any video, because I never watch them. I was suggesting you don't waste your time trying to install an unsupported OS on hardware it never supported.

Comment: @Millways  Thanks for the clarification